# use index.html page of angular as a controller view

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am using Asp.Net core angular template. I want to use index.html page as a view of my controller.

For that i have changed name of index.html to index.cshtml. and return that page from my controller. 
also changed index page of angular in angular.json file 
`"index": "src/index.cshtml",`

Index.cshtml (index file of angular)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular_DotNetCore</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/ClientApp/src/index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i am loading that index.cshtml page, Angular is not loading in `<app-root>`, Only showing Loading... text that is already written in `<app-root>Loading...</app-root>` tag.

Comment: In your code above you are not loading in `<app-root>`, you are loading in `<app-home>`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @CAlex
 not intentional, I have updated in question

Comment: If you're using angular cli, an angular build will modify your index.html page (add script tags for generated JS files). That's why we decided to keep the angular app static and load dynamic parts during angular startup https://www.intertech.com/Blog/angular-4-tutorial-run-code-during-app-initialization/

Comment: Why dont you use default angular template of vs ?

Comment: @TonyNgo I want to use third party server side controls and angular in same page,

Comment: Umang, Your index.html must containt the "bundles" scripts. Angular (when you use ng-serve or ng-build --prod) add this buldles files to the index.html. So build your app using ng-build --prod, look for the index.html generated and use this. NOTE: this is **not** a response of using razor page with Angular, this required more than a comment